# Como obtener la ruta correctamente con php, jquery y mi controlador desde una funcion con parametro

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Tengo que pasar un dato por un parámetro para luego mostrarlo en mi modal y así se muestre mi archivo correctamente, cuando lo hago de forma manual colocando los datos directos si carga y se muestra correctamente, pero cuando intento pasarlo por parámetros no me carga y da un error de sintaxis, podrían ayudarme porfavor? al parecer el openModelPDF(url) no carga correctamente cuando le asigno el parametro desde la bd, la base de datos todo carga correctamente.

este es mi index.php

```
 <!--Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalPdf" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalPdf" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ver archivo</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <iframe id="iframePDF" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- fi de modal-->
```

este es mi js: consultarStatus.js

```
function openModelPDF(partd_file) {
$('#modalPdf').modal('show');
```

// $('#iframePDF').attr('src','http://localhost/sistema/view/ConsultarStatus/uploadfile/files/531421209.pdf');
$('#iframePDF').attr('src','http://localhost/sistema/view/ConsultarStatus/uploadfile/' + partd_file);
}

alli esta comentado lo que funciona cuando quito el parametro y si me carga de esa forma , al parecer hay un error en el controlador pero la verdad no se que podria ser.

controlador: partes.php

```
//CONSULTANDO EL VISOR PDF DE FORMA AUTOMATICA Y DINAMICA
    case "listardetalle_consulta_statusPDF":
        $datos=$partes->list_partesdetalle_statusPDF($_POST["part_id"]);
        $data= Array();
        foreach($datos as $row){
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $row["partd_id"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["partd_obs"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["partd_file"];
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button"  id="'.$row["part_id"].'"  onclick="openModelPDF('.$row["partd_file"].');" class="btn btn-primary">Ver</button>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;                          
        }         
        $results = array(
            "sEcho"=>1,
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
            "aaData"=>$data);
        echo json_encode($results);
    break;
```

este es el error que me sale:
[image: esto es lo que me muestra cuando le doy click al boton ver]

Comment: Tú tienes un botón que en el onclick llama a openModelPDF. En el navegador hace click derecho a ese botón y pones inspeccionar (a veces hay que hacerlo 2 veces) y muéstranos el código html de ese botón

Answer (score 0):

estuve haciendo pruebas y llegue a la conclusion que el parametro enviado no me permite enviarlos letras , solo me permite enviar numeros, pero en mi otro formulario de prueba me lo permite normal, quizas de debe a una actualizacion de jquery.
por lo que lo deje por ahora solo numeros